# PHP uncheck option after set time

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm hoping someone can tell me what function I'd use to uncheck an option after a set amount of time.

Basically a wordpress/buddypress user would have an "Out of office" status displayed by a checkbox. They would set when the status should clear so the time out of office would be displayed along with the status.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tried looking for options, but the status would be lasting for days, and there are a number of users, so I wouldn't think timeout/delay functions would be the best choice

Comment: Are you using any database to store that data?

Comment: Sorry I updated to include that this is buddypress

Comment: Use a time function and check it using a conditional statement.